# JavaScript, how to auto update a div content without refreshing and autoscroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

ive been told that this can be achieve with javascript but im literally new with php and i would like to end my studies with it before i start with javascript, im making a simple chat just for practice, it logs the messages, it creates sessions with your name and logs you out, but i wouldnt like refresh the whole page to see if someone said something on my chat, ill post my files:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<title>Chat - Customer Module</title>  
<link href="dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">  
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');
include('action.php');
?>
</head>  
<body>  
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['name']))
    loginform();

if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
    include('chat.php');
}
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($_COOKIE);
var_dump($_POST);
?>
</body>  
</html>
```

im printing var_dumps to see if everything is going as expected.

action.php

```
<?php
session_start();

function loginform()
{
    echo '<div id="loginform">';
    echo '<form action="index.php" method="post">';
            echo '<p>Please enter your name to continue:</p>';
            echo '<label for="name">Name:</label>';
            echo '<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" class="btn" />';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
}

if(isset($_POST['enter']))
{
    if($_POST['name'] != '')
    {
        $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<span class="error">You input an invalid name</span>';
    }
}

if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['usermsg']))
    {
        $text = $_POST['usermsg'];

        $fp = fopen('log.html', 'a');
        fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgl'>(".date("g:i A").") <b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");
        fclose($fp);
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['exit']))
{
    $fp = fopen('log.html', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A").") <i>User <b>". $_SESSION['name'] ."</b> has left the chat session.</i><br></div>");
    fclose($fp);

    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

chat.php

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="welcome"> Welcome, <b><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></b>.</div>
        <div class="logout"> <form method="POST"><input type="submit" id="exit" name="exit" value="Exit" class="btn btn-danger"></form></div>
    </div>
    <div id="chatbox">
        <?php 
        if(file_exists('log.html'))
            echo file_get_contents('log.html');

        else
            echo 'ERROR: log empty or it wasnt found.';
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="chat">
        <form method="post">
            <input type="textarea" placeholder="Enter Message..." id="usermsg" name="usermsg" autofocus>
            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submitmsg" class="btn" name="submitmsg">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

everything is doing well, but ive been trying to find over the internet how to make the JQ functions i need for autoscroll and autoupdate, there has to be some kind of interval update for this, please help.

Comment: you're looking for $.ajax and scrollheight

Comment: yes, but how do i make the code?

Comment: google is your friend

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is what you need to submit the form and change content on-the-fly without refreshing the page.

Comment: alright, but thats from jquery?. i need to find how to do it

Comment: $.ajax it's what you need